# SQL find last date and last time of event

Tags: sql

I am trying to list the latest event (only one row output)

Basically the very last date of the event and the very last time of the event.

The below code doesn't work if it is max(starttime), but it works if it is min(starttime)

However, if I do min(starttime), it'll tell me the last date of the event but the first event of that last date.

I would like to get the result of the last event time of the last date. (therefore only 1 row output)

Any ideas?

```
SELECT * from Events
where dateheld in (select max(dateheld) from events)
AND starttime in (select max(starttime) from events)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be the logic as your WHERE statement could be generating two disjoint sets (the max(time) of the table does not share a row with the max(date)).  What about something such as the following: (DISTINCT ensures only one record)

```
SELECT MAX(dateheld) AS 'MaxDate', starttime 
FROM Events
WHERE starttime in 
      (SELECT MAX (starttime) AS temp FROM events)
```

Comment: terrific! i see... a subquery in a subquery.. nested (Y)

Comment: i'll accept this answer in 6 minutes because it doesn't allow me to accept now.

Comment: this won't work. any time 2 or more events have the same start time, all the matching records will be returned.

Comment: what do you mean by all matching records?
do you mean if theres 2 events with the same start time and date, itll return those 2 rows?

Comment: but then if there are 2 different Event ID's with the same start time and date, if you use distinct it'll filter out one of them right?

Comment: Start from the inside and work your way out. The first query selects the max dateheld. The second subquery then selects the max start time on that max dateheld (so far so good). The problem comes in the final where clause. ALL events that have a matching start time (say 8:00 AM) will appear in your result set.

Comment: @diophantine which revision are you referring to? I guess it doesn't matter. The SQL that was accepted as the answer was wrong. I think your query may work now, but the last where clause is unnecessary as it stands now.

Answer (score 1):

you can limit your result to the top 1 record returned:

```
select * from events
order by dateheld, starttime desc
limit 1
```

**edit to meet new requirement**

```
select max(starttime) as maxstart, dateheld
from events
where dateheld = (select max(dateheld) as maxdateheld from events)
```

Comment: erm that would work too but i'm now allowed to use Order By :)

Comment: yeah.
I did order by before and it worked. but then i realised we weren't allowed to use Order By in this question.

Comment: for future reference, you should tag it as homework. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much gangreen for your answer, however there are alot more columns other than the one you've listed in your new answer.
well.. thinking about it i could just list all the columns of that table..